# How to show the crossfilter output?

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I have started to learn the crossfilter to group my datas. I took a sample code from web and I am able to see the results in console using console.log(objects). But how can I show them in page, in a table format? page looks empty.

I am trying as below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.9/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var arr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < 100; k++) arr.push({a: i, e: { b: j, c: k}});
        }
    }

    var cf = crossfilter(arr),
        a  = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.a; }),
        e  = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.e; });

    var counts = e.group(function(d) { return d.b; })
                  .reduceCount()
                  .orderNatural()
                  .top(Infinity);

    console.log(counts);

    </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can we use d3 for table rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DC.js](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/).  DC nicely wraps D3 and CrossFilter so you can quickly and easily display graphs--plus the graphs can be used to interactively filter each other.  It is powerful and very easy to use.

Also, check out DC's DataTable control, which is the control to display tabular filtered data.